# Android: Problem with creating new object from Firebase document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following data stored in Firebase:

```
id(document id)
 - carName: BMW 
 - carModel: 318
 - carProductionYear: 2011
 - carFuel: petrol
 - carColor: white
 - ...
```

At some point in the application, I want to show only a certain amount of the data. That's why I've prepared this class:

```
class CarBasic{
   private String carName;
   private String carModel;
   private String carFuel;
}
```

But when typing this code, a message: "Change signature of Carbasic" appears

```
carsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    List<CarBasic> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                        list.add(new CarBasic(document.get("carName"),document.get("carModel"),document.get("carFuel")));
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CarBasicInfoActivity.this, "Error while loading the data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to take only this type of objects (CarBasic) and pass them to a RecyclerView as a source. But how can I do the parsing between Firebase and my actual object?

**EDITED**

The error message:

```
         Required type     Provided
carName:  String            Object
carModel: String            Object
carFuel:  Stirng            Object
```

Comment: You are trying to add objects of type CarRoute to a List of type CarBasic.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Does `CardRoute` extend `CarBasic`?

Comment: @DougStevenson my bad, I've updated the question I just wanted to keep it simple that's why I provided simple classes

Comment: @AlexMamo no no, it's a mistake on my side. The question is updated.

Comment: Please add the entire message that you get.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. So basically Firebase parses a document data to whatever class we provide, as long as the attributes of that class match the keys of the document. (I though that the class must match always all of the document attributes, but it's not necessary)

In my case, the class is CarBasic (simple POJO) and defined in this way:

```
class CarBasic{
  private String carName;
  private String carModel;
  private String carFuel;

  //Empty constructor
  //Constructor with all attributes

  //Getters
}
```

A typical document key-value pair in my concrete example:

```
id(document id)
 - carName: BMW 
 - carModel: 318
 - carProductionYear: 2011
 - carFuel: petrol
 - carColor: white
 - carKm: 198000
 - carMotor: 2.0
 - carType: convertible
 - carDoorsNumber: 5
```

So a reference to my collection is:

```
CollectionReference carsRef = FirebaseFireStore.getInstance().collection("vehicles").document(user.getUid()).collection("availableCars");
```

(user.getUid() comes from the Auth part. Replace it with whatever name you want)

And initializing the RecyclerView is as follows:

```
Query query = carsRef.orderBy("carName", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CarBasic> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<CarBasic>()
                .setQuery(query,CarBasic.class)
                .build();
CarsAdapter carsAdapter = new CarsAdapter(options);
RecyclerView recyclerViewCars = findViewById(R.id.carsRecyclerView);
recyclerViewCars.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerViewCars.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerViewCars.setAdapter(carsAdapter);
```

Hope, this helps anyone, who has problems with passing specific document fields to `RecyclerView`.